# Breaking a for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to break a for loop that checks reads lines in another module. I notice that this function runs through every line of code in the module, but it only returns the boolean for the last line... how can I stop the loop as soon as it sees a false WITHOUT USING the break function? You don't have to worry about opening the file, I am capable of doing that

```
read_lines = file_handle.readlines()

for next_line in all_lines:

    check = next_line[0]

    if (check == ' '):
        result = False

    else:
        result = True
return result
```

Comment: *WITHOUT USING the break function* but WHY ? However you may enclose your for loop inside a function and return it, if you really don't wanna use `break`

Comment: `return False if check == ' ' else True`

Comment: A simple `return False` will do the job.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I heard in computer science, breaks should never be used...

Comment: @KlausD.Is there a way of doing it with only one return statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand what exactly you want to return, and under *what* conditions, because this greatly affects what your function returns and when. For example, do you want to check if `check == ' '` for even a single case? In which case, one return is enough.

```
for next_line in all_lines:
    if next_line[0] == ' ':
        return False

return True
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `any`:

```
return not any(x[0] == ' ' for x in all_lines)
```

Or, its counterpart, `all`, with an inverted condition:

```
return all(x[0] != ' ' for x in all_lines)
```

Note that `str.isspace()` is a more pythonic way of checking if a string is a whitespace character, although that makes a check for all whitespace characters (including tabs and newlines, not just whitespace characters).

Comment: Uhm... since I'm running through all the lines, I'm guessing it's more than one case? I wanna use your 3rd method, but I don't think it works for multiple cases?

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't output return true when it gets run passed? I don't understand the algorithm behind this

Comment: @DaquarisGeorgino It's an all or nothing approach. Either all the tests pass and you return True, or even one test fails and you return False.

Comment: I see... so if even one tests fails, it returns false? but wouldn't the return true afterwards overwrite the return false?

Comment: @DaquarisGeorgino not so. Because once a function returns, it can't come back and return something else like that.

Comment: Ah.. makes sense. Once again, thanks for you the help! I would commend you, but my rep is too low :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a return statement in your code , which will exit function as soon as it finds a match

```
read_lines = file_handle.readlines()

for next_line in all_lines:

    check = next_line[0]

    if (check == ' '):
        result = False
        #add a return here
        return result
    else:
        result = True
```

`return result`

Comment: Is there a way to do it with only one return statement?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : Can you plz explain what is not correct ? You mean to say it has two return statements ?

Comment: I mean to say you have probably not understood what OP is trying to do. See my answer for details. Cheers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : His question is not to use break later he mentioned not to use two return statements. Anyway my answer is using two return statements

Comment: Yeah but OP doesn't know what they want, and sometimes it's more important to give OP what they need, not what they want.